# Joomla 2.5 how to detect failed front-end log-in attempt

Tags: plugins, joomla, authentication, joomla2.5

I am developing a Joomla 2.5 system plug-in that needs to perform certain tasks when a front-end visitor has attempted a log-in but failed.

How can I detect in my system plug-in that a user authentication has failed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an event `onUserLoginFailure` that you can catch.

> **onUserLoginFailure**
>
> **Description:** This event is triggered whenever a user authentication
>   request is failed by any plugin.
>
> **Parameters:** Two parameters. The credentials array for the user (see
>   onAuthenticate), and the JAuthenticateResponse that caused the
>   failure.
>
> **Return Value:** Unknown. The return value appears to be ignored in any
>   case.
>
> **Used in files:** libraries/joomla/application/user/authentication.php

Reference: [onUserLoginFailure](https://docs.joomla.org/Plugin/Events/User#onUserLoginFailure)

Comment: You are my champion! Thanks a lot!